# Custom number format in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm using Freemarker GAE v 2.3.22 and i want to create a custom number format.
How do I achieve this? I have looked up in the documentation files and could not find anything related to custom number formats in this version.

Comment: See https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_string_for_number

Comment: I'm using GAE compliant freemarker . So,can't import TemplateNumberFormatFactory and hence can't set custom number format.

Comment: Then either upgrade or add a method to your data model to handle number formatting https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_quickstart_createdatamodel.html

Comment: Adding a method seems okay

Comment: Why can't you upgrade again? All versions, such as `2.3.27-incubating` (the last stable currently), has GAE version. The Maven artifact name is `freemarker-gae`. It's highly recommended to upgrade even if you don't use any new features because of better error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Custom format support (of the kind that uses `TemplateNumberFormatFactory` etc.) was added in version 2.3.24. Of course it's available in the GAE variations as well. Each 2.3.x release has both normal (`org.freemarker:freemarker` Maven artifact) and GAE (`org.freemarker:freemarker-gae`) variation. So just increase the version number of your `freemarker-gae` dependency.